# MongoDB $filter nested array by date does not work

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have a document with a nested array which looks like this:

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    data: [
      [
        ISODate("2000-01-01T00:00:00Z"),
        2,
        3
      ],
      [
        ISODate("2000-01-03T00:00:00Z"),
        2,
        3
      ],
      [
        ISODate("2000-01-05T00:00:00Z"),
        2,
        3
      ]
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    data: []
  }
]
```

As you can see, we have an array of arrays. For each element in the `data` array, the first element is a date.

I wanted to create an aggregation pipeline which filters only the elements of `data` where the date is larger than a given date.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$match": {
      "id": 1
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      "data": {
        "$filter": {
          "input": "$data",
          "as": "entry",
          "cond": {
            "$gt": [
              "$$entry.0",
              ISODate("2000-01-04T00:00:00Z")
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

The problem is that with `$gt`, this just returns an empty array for `data`. With `$lt` this returns all elements. So the filtering clearly does not work.

Expected result:

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "data": [
      [
        ISODate("2000-01-05T00:00:00Z"),
        2,
        3
      ]
    ]
  }
]
```

Any ideas?

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/1vXYnCfANCU)

Comment: In the nested array, the year of the date is **2000**. While you try to filter with the date greater than **2020**. 2000 never greater than 2020.

Comment: @YongShun you are right. But changing to 2000 does not solve the problem either :/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe the issue is that when you write `$$entry.0`, MongoDB is trying to evaluate `entry.0` as a variable name, when in reality the variable is named `entry`. You could make use of the [`$first` array operator](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/first-array-element/#-first--array-operator-) in order to get the first element like so:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$match": {
      "id": 1
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      "data": {
        "$filter": {
          "input": "$data",
          "as": "entry",
          "cond": {
            "$gt": [
              {
                $first: "$$entry"
              },
              ISODate("2000-01-04T00:00:00Z")
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Mongo playground example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/xlqVeRZyVRK)

Answer (score 2):

Don't think `$$entry.0` work to get the first element of the array. Instead, use `$arrayElemAt` operator.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$match": {
      "id": 1
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      "data": {
        "$filter": {
          "input": "$data",
          "as": "entry",
          "cond": {
            "$gt": [
              {
                "$arrayElemAt": [
                  "$$entry",
                  0
                ]
              },
              ISODate("2000-01-04T00:00:00Z")
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Sample Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/l9B15DE2S5W)

Answer (score 0):

to specify which element in the array you are comparing it is better to use `$arrayElemAt` instead of `$$ARRAY.0`. you must pass 2 parameters while using `$arrayElemAt`, the first one is the array which in your case is `$$entry`, and the second one is the index which in your case is `0`

this is the solution I came up with:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$match": {
      "id": 1
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      "data": {
        "$filter": {
          "input": "$data",
          "as": "entry",
          "cond": {
            "$gt": [
              {
                "$arrayElemAt": [
                  "$$entry",
                  0
                ]
              },
              ISODate("2000-01-04T00:00:00Z")
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/LZeS0MIVmJq)